# 405 Method Not Allowed while accessing UBER api

Tags: uber-api

For booking of uber cabs from native android application i'm following this  tutorial on [https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/curl][2]

I'm following step1 and i'm getting UBER signup page but in step2 i am getting this response "
405 Method Not Allowed

## Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

".
 Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a http get request instead of a http post method request.

Comment: i used post request also. but it's showing {
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}

Comment: Please share the exact request/response.

Comment: Thanks for reaching this is my request "https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token". This is a post request and in body i'm sending client_id ,redirect_uri as "http://localhost" ,client_secret,grant_type as "authorization_code",refresh_token as "q1uR43DL16E7cTRIUNziySKdvdzqrz#_". refresh token is generated from authorization request. Thanks

Comment: Can you share example code and exact request/response (without credentials)?